# Is there a way to import certificate from azure keyvault to azure web app in .NET?

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

In azure cli we have this command to import/bind certificates to azure app from keyvault.az

webapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint {certificate-thumbprint} --name MyWebapp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --ssl-type SNI

I couldn't find equivalent library in .NET to do the same (I am using C#).
Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @john your hint was more than enough for me to look this up.
The method that you pointed helps in ssl binding with the existing certificate.
But I need to import the certificate in my azure web app [image]. Any API for that?

```
var webApp1 = azure.WebApps
                .GetById(<your resouce Id as a string>)
                .Update()
                .DefineSslBinding()
                .ForHostname(<host name as a string>)
                .WithPfxCertificateToUpload(<certificate as a string>,
                    <password as a string>)
                .WithSniBasedSsl()
                .Attach()
                .Apply();
```

Comment: I imagine you would have to export the certificate from the keyvault (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificateclient) first and the add it to the WebApp with the WithPfxCertificateToUpload method.

Comment: That's the tricky part  here, the method WithPfxCertificateToUpload doesn't uploads the certificate to webapp it directly ssl binds it with the specified hostname in the app. If you can provide with a sample code how can we add it to app that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "upload" to the WebApp? Binding the certificate to the WebApp is the ultimate purpose, no?

Comment: yup that's the ultimate goal. But wanna if uploading can be done using API as it is done using azure portal in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a fluent API to access all the Azure services.

By accessing the [App Service API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/appservice?view=azure-dotnet) you should be able to [assign an existing certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.hostnamesslbinding.updatedefinition.iwithcertificate-1.withexistingcertificate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_AppService_Fluent_HostNameSslBinding_UpdateDefinition_IWithCertificate_1_WithExistingCertificate_System_String_) to it.

Comment: This provides no way to *import* an existing certificate from a key vault.